# How to export mp3 file with AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, macos, audio, avfoundation

I'm trying to export my asset as an `.mp3` file using `AVAssetWriter`.

Here's how I create an instance of it:

```
writer = try! AVAssetWriter(url: outputURL,
                            fileType: AVFileType.mp3)
```

Unfortunately, it throws the error:

> [AVAssetWriter initWithURL:fileType:error:] **Invalid file type UTI.**
>
> Available file types are: *com.scenarist.closed-caption, org.w3.webvtt,
> public.aiff-audio, com.apple.m4v-video,
> org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio, com.apple.m4a-audio,
> com.microsoft.waveform-audio, com.apple.coreaudio-format,
> public.mpeg-4, com.apple.itunes-timed-text, com.apple.quicktime-movie,
> public.aifc-audio*

I'm running this code on macOS 10.15.
I find it hard to believe that there's no support for exporting an mp3 file. Can anyone guide me on how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find it hard to believe that there's no support for exporting an mp3 file

Overcome your difficulty and believe it. Due to a complex of copyright issues, Apple has no license to provide any native capacity to create MP3 files. You might find some third party library that can do it, but you won't do it with AVAssetWriter.

Comment: Surely you have noticed that iTunes can read an MP3 file and play or convert it, but cannot convert anything else  to MP3? And wondered why? It's the same reason.

Comment: Damn, I'd never suspect there are such copyright issues with our old, good mp3 format. Thanks for the answer @matt. I already see that some people have tried using LAME library to encode mp3. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Google "mp3 copyright" and prepare to learn more about the law than you ever wanted to...!